# Not able to use EmailOptions Property in microsoft Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I am experimenting with the EmailOptions property.
I found the example on Microsoft Docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.emailoptions) and I am trying out. But it is giving the error: " Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method "

I have added references to MS Word and Excel. What am i missing?

```
Option Explicit

Sub x()
With Outlook.Application.EmailOptions.EmailSignature
    If .NewMessageSignature = "" Then
        MsgBox "There is no signature for new " 
    Else
        MsgBox "There is signature for new e-mail"
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`EmailOptions` property is exposed by the `Word.Application` object, not by the `Outlook.Application` object.

Comment: I used the same code after changing outlook application to a word application object but its not working

``Sub x()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application

With WordApp.EmailOptions.EmailSignature
``

Comment: Please show your code that initializes the WordApp variable.